# Chain Multiple MapReduce Jobs with sending data to same mappers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm facing an issue with a chained multiple mapreduce jobs.

The current scenario works as follows:
The application process 2 data-sources, each of them go to a separated mapper using "MultipleInputs" from 2 different directories

First Job reads the inputs in 2 Mappers, process the data and output data on 2 different directories using "MultipleOutputs".

Now, the second job should work on the output of the first task using the same task ids of the first job.

---

For example,

**Job1:** 2 Different Mappers, 1 Reducer

- Mapper1_1 reads datasource1 directory, creates 2 tasks to process them and output ds1/ds1-m-00000 and ds1/ds1-m-00001 intermediate files
- Mapper1_2 reads datasource2 directory, creates 1 task to process it and output ds2/ds2-m-00002 intermediate file
- Reducer1 makes some calculations and outputs some statistics

**Job2:** 2 Different Mappers, 1 Reducer

- Mapper2_1 reads ds1 directory, creates 2 tasks to process the 2 intermediate files.
- Mapper2_2 reads ds2 directory, creates 1 task to process the intermediate file.
- Reducer2 makes some calculations to output the final result

For some reasons, the same task id must be used in the second job as the ones generated in the first job but actually, the task ids is generated randomly, sometimes in the second job, they are generated like first jobs and the process complete successfully and sometimes not.

Is there anyway to control generating the same task id for the 2 jobs or any other method to generate a unique number to identify the same file in both jobs?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same task id?

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr The first job should count different "types" of records in each file and in each mapper, it outputs the same input record after some manipulations as an additional input. In the setup method of second job mapper, I need to initialize an array with an initial index for each "type" which depends on its global position across all files. So, I need to know the count of preceding record for the same type. For that reason, the same mapper should process same files to be synchronized.